# Tkinter Make Multiple Column/Single Row Grid Fit Frame Size

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to fit frame containing buttons to the grid. But I don't know how to recize the buttons depending on the grid cells size.

Below is my code :

```
def __init__(self, parent, controller):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self,parent)
    
    IWidth = self.winfo_width()
    FrmBtn= tk.Frame(self,bg='black',width = IWidth)
    FrmBtn.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH,pady=10,padx=10)
    FrmBtn.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    button = tk.Button(FrmBtn, text="Tab1",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TestPage1))
    button.grid(row=0,column=0,sticky="W")
    
    button1 = tk.Button(FrmBtn, text="Tab2",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TestPage1))
    button1.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky="W")
    
    button3 = tk.Button(FrmBtn, text="Tab3",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TestPage1))
    button3.grid(row=0,column=2,sticky="W")
    
    button4 = tk.Button(FrmBtn, text="Tab4",
                        command=lambda: controller.show_frame(TestPage1))
    button4.grid(row=0,column=3,sticky="W")
    FrmW= tk.Frame(self,bg='grey',width = IWidth)
    FrmW.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH,pady=10,padx=10)
```

When I run the code I got :

[image]

but when I use cursor to resize the window I got :

[image]

or :

[image]

The Excepted Output would be stuff like :

[image]

or :

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to use `Grid.rowconfigure()` and `Grid.rowconfigure()`.

In example code I commented the way yo can do it and what configure line do.
Basicly it takes six buttons and place them in two columns (3 rows), and they resize with window.
Example code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import Grid, Button

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("resize button")
root.geometry("500x500")


# here you need to put on what do you want to use row configure, index(row) and weight
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)  # we use on root, row=0 weight=1
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 0, weight=1)

#configure 2nd row
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 1, weight=1)


#configure 3rd row
Grid.rowconfigure(root, 2, weight=1)

#configure 2nd column
Grid.columnconfigure(root, 1, weight=1)

button1 = Button(root, text="Button1")
button2 = Button(root, text="Button2")
button3 = Button(root, text="Button3")

button1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
button2.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky="nsew")
button3.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="nsew")

button1_1 = Button(root, text="Button1_1")
button2_1 = Button(root, text="Button2_1")
button3_1 = Button(root, text="Button3_1")

button1_1.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky="nsew")
button2_1.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")
button3_1.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky="nsew")

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add to replace `Sticky = "w"` by `Sticky="nsew"`

Comment: If you do that, then you will have smaller buttons that are original size  sticky="w" , it is west or left center. If you do "nsew" then you have buttons to fill screen size. Thats difference. So if you need small buttons, then yes, sticky="w" is correct, if you need large buttons then  sticky="nsew" is correct.